# How to extract and sum character elements in a list together

Tags: r

I have a list (which is a column in a dataframe) containing strings such as:

```
list("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 2 m", 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 2 x 2m", 
    "2 pieces of tissue, the larger measuring 4 x 2 x 2 m", c("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 5 x 4 x 2 m", 
    "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 6 x 2 x 1 m", 
    "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 1 m"), 
    NA_character_, c("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 2 m", 
    "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 5 x 2 x 2 m", 
    "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 2 x 1 m"), 
    NA_character_, "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 8 x 2 x 2m")
```

This list is generated from the line

`x$NumbOfBx <- str_extract_all(x[,y], "([A-Za-z]*|[0-9]) (specimens|pieces).*?(([0-9]).*?x.*?([0-9]).*?x.*?([0-9])).*?([a-z])")` as part of the function below

I would like to extract the sum of the number of pieces of tissue for each element in the list. I have been trying:

```
function(x,y) {
  x<-data.frame(x)
      x$NumbOfBx <- str_extract_all(x[,y], "([A-Za-z]*|[0-9]) (specimens|pieces).*?(([0-9]).*?x.*?([0-9]).*?x.*?([0-9])).*?([a-z])")
      x$NumbOfBx <- sapply(x$NumbOfBx, function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(x$NumbOfBx, "^\\d+")))))

  x$NumbOfBxs <- unlist(x$NumbOfBx)
  x$NumbOfBx <- as.numeric(str_extract(x$NumbOfBx, "^.*?\\d"))
  return(x)
}
```

but I get the error

```
Error in x$NumbOfBx : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: This line `x$NumbOfBx <- sapply(x$NumbOfBx, function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(x$NumbOfBx, "^\\d+")))))` is probably the culprit. You are defining a function inside the `sapply` but the parameter you chose is `x`, which is already the variable name for dataframe. Essentially, you are overwriting the variable x with elements in `x$NumbOfBx`. Those elements are probably the `atomic vectors` the error is complaining about. You need to change that line to something else. Perhaps, use `apply` if you have to the `$` operator.

Comment: I have changed the f in function to a p and at least I get to error, although now I get NAs returned only (sum not done). How can I get it to sum?

Comment: `sum(vals, na.rm = T)`? Here `vals` is the set of values whose sum you're calculating. But the important part is `na.rm` since that's what takes the `NA`'s out.

Comment: `sapply(yourlist, function(x) sum(as.numeric(gsub("(\\d+) pieces of tissue.*", "\\1", x))))`

Comment: Hi @SebastianZeki if any of the answers helped you, please consider accepting one by clicking on the check mark. This lets the community know the answer worked for you and that the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data

```
L <- list("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 2 m", 
NA_character_, NA_character_, "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 2 x 2m", 
"2 pieces of tissue, the larger measuring 4 x 2 x 2 m", c("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 5 x 4 x 2 m", 
"4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 6 x 2 x 1 m", 
"4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 1 m"), 
NA_character_, c("4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 3 x 2 m", 
"4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 5 x 2 x 2 m", 
"4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4 x 2 x 1 m"), 
NA_character_, "4 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 8 x 2 x 2m")
```

#### one liner base R solution

```
sapply(L, function(x) sum(as.numeric(substr(x, regexpr("\\d+(?= pieces of tissue)", x, perl=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE),
                                               regexpr("\\d+(?= pieces of tissue)", x, perl=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE)))))
```

#### Output

```
4 NA NA  4  2 12 NA 12 NA  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Briefly, assuming your data is a list, you can extract the numeric value preceding the words sample|specimen, convert it to a number and then aggregate the counts found in each vector included in the list. It's the same strategy you proposed, with a few modifications...

```
# Assuming your list is defined as my.list

xtr.pieces <- function(ml) {
  my.sums <- lapply(ml, (function(el){
    sum (sapply(el, (function(tmp){
      if (!is.na(tmp)) {
        loc <- regexpr("[0-9]{1,2}.{0,3}[sample|specimen]", tmp)
        if (loc > 0) {
          tmp <- substr(tmp, loc, loc + attributes(loc)$match.length)
          as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", tmp))
        }
      } else {
        0
      }
    })))
  }))
  return (my.sums)
}
```

NAs are counted as 0 here. You can execute, and you get:

```
unlist(xtr.pieces(ml))
[1]  4  0  0  4  2 12  0 12  0  4
```